# Render Error Message on VisualForce page with output panel

Tags: visualforce, controller

I want to be able to render an error message on the page if a case record variable Closed_Days_Beyond_30_Days__c is true but unsure how to make this work. If the boolean is true, set the error message. If the boolean is false, then continue opening the modal.

VF

```
<apex:pageMessages id="caseErrorMessage" />
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!oCase.Status=='Closed'}">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" reRender="caseErrorMessage" class="btn btn-default cbtnclose cBtnNew" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_Open"></a>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Controller

```
public void doClosedCaseValidation(){
    if(oCase.Closed_Days_Beyond_30_Days__c)
    {
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'This case has been closed for more than five (5) business days. Please submit a new case and reference this case number for prompt assistance.'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `apex:pageMessage`

```
  <apex:pageMessage rendered="{!hasCaseClosedError}" severity="2" 
        summary="This case has been closed for more than five (5) business days. Please submit a new case and reference this case number for prompt assistance."/>
```

**In your controller**

```
public Boolean hasCaseClosedError {
  get {
     return ... your logic here ...
  } private set;
}
```

**Alternative**

Or, you can do this without the controller logic if the `oCase` variable is exposed to the VF page with a public getter

```
<apex:pageMessage rendered="{!oCase.Closed_Days_Beyond_30_Days__c}" severity="2" 
        summary="This case has been closed for more than five (5) business days. Please submit a new case and reference this case number for prompt assistance."/>
```

**Alternative 2**

If the VF page is associated to a standardController (i.e. not a custom controller), and oCase is the same as the standard Case record that the page is invoked on

```
<apex:pageMessage rendered="{!Case.Closed_Days_Beyond_30_Days__c}" severity="2" 
        summary="This case has been closed for more than five (5) business days. Please submit a new case and reference this case number for prompt assistance."/>
```